# How to decode encoded data from deep autoencoder in Keras (unclarity in tutorial)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have followed the tutorial "Building Autoencoders in Keras":
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

The first, simple, solution works fine. But in the section "Deep autoencoder" the code provided in the tutorial does not seem to work fully.

Here is my code (just until where the problem appears), which is just copied from the turorial:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

encoding_dim = 32

input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)  # Multiple encoding
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)  # and decoding layers.
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)

encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))  # Crash happens here.
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))  # Crash happens here
  File "/Users/paulmagnus/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 569, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/Users/paulmagnus/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 479, in assert_input_compatibility
    ' but got shape ' + str(x_shape))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_6: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 128 but got shape (None, 32)
```

I am guessing that `decoder`is connected to the wrong decoding layer and/or that the shape of its input or output is wrong. But what should I do about it?

The `decoder` is not necessary for the `autoencoder` to work. I can perform the learning and encode the images following the rest of the tutorial. But without `decoder` I am not able to decode the images back to original format to see if they actually look good. The tutorial doesn't mention anything about this and just shows the decoded images without a word. I guess the author assumed whatever change he did to `decoder` to achieve this was trivial.

To clarify: the single-layer version works fine, where instead of 3 encoding and 3 decoding layers we just have

```
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
```

and everything else is equal as above. Then there is no error and I can use `decoder` to recreate the images.

Comment: Hi PaulMag; I think your question is code-related and about debugging your Keras model setup, not so much about statistics or deep learning techniques. If so, its topically better related to StackOverflow's "mission", not CrossValidated.

Comment: @fnl Yes, you are correct. I was unsure on which platform to ask this. Should I repost it on StackOverflow and delete it from CrossValidated?

Comment: I just figured out that migration is a thing. I have flagged this question for migration to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
```

This code works for single-layer because only last layer is decoder in this case and

```
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
```

this line calls for last layer.

for 3-layer encoders and decoders, you have to call all 3 layers for defining decoder.
i was doing the same tutorial so i have written the code like this.

```
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))

deco = autoencoder.layers[-3](encoded_input)
deco = autoencoder.layers[-2](deco)
deco = autoencoder.layers[-1](deco)
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, deco).
```

it works fine now.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense, but I would not have guessed. I thought we had already linked those layers together. That's a big hole in the tutorial.

Comment: @PaulMag I think we did already link those layers together, but we linked them with the image input to the autoencoder, rather than encoded input which we want to be the input. Keras at this point doesn't figure out where we want our `encoded_input` to be inserted, so we have to rebuild the graph with it inserted in.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution & explanaition! It saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

new__1 answer lacks scalability for when you have more layers than that.
You can leverage the fact that you know the bottleneck size, iterate over the layers, and start adding layers once you "hit" the bottleneck layer.

```py
def build_decoder_from_model(model, bottleneck_size=1):
    decoder_input = keras.Input((bottleneck_size,))

    in_decoder = False
    x = None  # Just a place holder to suppress pycharm warnings.
    for l in model.layers:
        if in_decoder:
            x = l(x)
        if l.input_shape[1] == bottleneck_size:
            in_decoder = True
            x = l(encoder_input)

    decoder = keras.Model(decoder_input, x)
    return decoder
```